# Why does Scala define a "+=" operator for Short and Byte types?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, scala-2.9

Given the following scala code:

```
var short: Short = 0
short += 1        // error: type mismatch
short += short    // error: type mismatch
short += 1.toByte // error: type mismatch
```

I don't questioning the underlying typing - it's clear that "Short + value == Int".

My questions are:
1. Is there any way at all that the operator can be used?
2. If not, then why is the operator available for use on Short & Byte?

[And by extension  *=, |= &=, etc.]

Comment: Actually, Short doesn't have method "+=" or "*=", you can look the doc for Short http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Short  . x someoperator=y are translating to x = x someoperator y by the compiler automatically.

Comment: @Eastsun But neither does Int :-) `a op= b` is syntactic sugar for the expanded form: `a = a op b`, which explains the type error (Short + Short -> Int). It doesn't explain why the decision was made or what use this construct might -- or might not -- have. (In C# it is perfectly legal to do `byte+=1` but not `byte=byte+1`, and the behavior is specific in the standard -- there is an implicit cast back to the LHS type in C#).

Comment: @pst Yes , you can do the same thing in Java as in C# (If I remember correctly.)

Comment: @Eastsun Goodness, I try to forget that language ;-) I guess then two approaches to make it useful are: 1) implicit cast/coercion back to LFS (ala C#) or 2) make Short + Short -> Short; the first is just not specified per the SLS, so then that just leaves debate over type-promotion on additions... (Perhaps the latter is to deal with Java type-promotions? Or just overflow errors? Or...)

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that "+(Short)" on Short class is defined as:

```
def +(x: Short): Int
```

So it always returns an Int.

Given this you end up not being able to use the += "operator" because the + operation evaluates to an Int which (obviously) can not be assigned to the "short" var in the desugared version:

```
short = short + short
```

As for your second question, it is "available" because when the scala compiler finds expressions like:

```
x K= y
```

And if x is a var and K is any symbolic operator and there is K method in x then the compiler translates or "desugar" it to:

```
x = x K y
```

And then tries to continue compilation with that.