# What is the most concise way to increment a variable of type Short in Scala?

Tags: scala, primitive, primitive-types

I've been working a bit lately on implementing a binary network protocol in Scala. Many of the fields in the packets map naturally to Scala Shorts. I would like to concisely increment a `Short` variable (not a value). Ideally, I would like something like `s += 1` (which works for **Ints**).

```
scala> var s = 0:Short
s: Short = 0

scala> s += 1
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: Short
              s += 1
                ^

scala> s = s + 1
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: Short
       s = s + 1
             ^

scala> s = (s + 1).toShort
s: Short = 1

scala> s = (s + 1.toShort)
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: Short
       s = (s + 1.toShort)
              ^

scala> s = (s + 1.toShort).toShort
s: Short = 2
```

The `+=` operator is not defined on `Short`, so there appears to be an implicit converting `s` to an `Int` preceding the addition. Furthermore `Short`'s + operator returns an `Int`.
Here's how it works for Ints:

```
scala> var i = 0
i: Int = 0

scala> i += 1

scala> i
res2: Int = 1
```

For now I'll go with `s = (s + 1).toShort`

Any ideas?

Comment: Somewhat belated, I've found a [related post] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975245). Ende Neu's answer, with Paul's extension provide a better solution. The linked post does illuminate somewhat why Paul's extension works.

Comment: Also interesting to note, is that the JVM doesn't directly support arithmetic operations on `shorts`. The bytecode instructions always operate on `int`s. See the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.3).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could define an implicit method that will convert the `Int` to a `Short`:

```
scala> var s: Short = 0
s: Short = 0

scala> implicit def toShort(x: Int): Short = x.toShort
toShort: (x: Int)Short

scala> s = s + 1
s: Short = 1
```

The compiler will use it to make the types match. Note though that implicits also have a shortfall, somewhere you could have a conversion happening without even knowing why, just because the method was imported in the scope, code readability suffers too.